# Convert NO2 concentration in Sentinel-5P data from mol/m2 to μg/m3 on the ground level

Tags: atmosphere, atmospheric-chemistry, air-pollution, satellites, weatherdata

**Sentinel-5P** satellite provides [high-resolution data products](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-5p/products-algorithms) on concentration levels for several atmospheric trace gases (NO<sub>2</sub>, SO<sub>2</sub>, O<sub>3</sub>
, and others), which are measured in **mol/m<sup>2</sup>** within the total or tropospheric column. Is it possible to deduce concentrations for a specific slice of the troposphere?

Namely, I'm interested to get NO<sub>2</sub> raster to work in GIS, where each pixel of it will contain NO<sub>2</sub> level in **μg/m<sup>3</sup>**, 0–50 meters above the ground. I've already read *Product User Information*, *Algorithm Theoretical Basis Document*, and *Input Output Data Definition* related to the corresponding Sentinel-5 NO<sub>2</sub> product. However, it didn't give me an idea of how to get μg/m<sup>3</sup> for the near-ground level. Is it feasible at all? I guess it is, as in the [Copernicus European air quality portal](https://regional.atmosphere.copernicus.eu), which uses Sentinel-5P data for the air pollution forecast, I see that they show NO<sub>2</sub> concentrations in μg/m3.

**Is there some workflow to do it?**

*A screenshot from the Copernicus European air quality portal:*
[image: A screenshot from the Copernicus European air quality portal]

P.S. I have good experience in remote sensing of land surface and geographic information systems, but I've never worked with weather/atmosphere data before.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean completely *at* ground level (where we breath), or more generally near the surface?

Comment: Near the surface, like from 0 to 50 m above the ground. It's needed to study the air we breathe.

Comment: Have you find a way to make the conversion from mol/m2 to ug/m3? I am facing the same problem and I do not know how to do it

Comment: related question: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/8860/convert-omi-no2-vertical-column-density-molecules-cm2-into-mixing-ratio-ppm?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ...measured in mol/m² within the total or tropospheric column. Is it possible to deduce concentrations for a specific slice of the troposphere?

Not really, since you have a crucial bit of information missing: the vertical distribution.

Your alternatives are:

- Combine satellite data with a model to estimate near-surface NO₂.  The model may be able to estimate what surface conditions may be associated with what total column conditions, depending on other factors.
- Stick with total column data.
- Use a different data source, preferably ground-based measurements.  Although a limb sounder does a much better job at getting a high vertical resolution (at expense of horizontal resolution), below 50 metre is too close to the surface.

Measuring the vertical distribution with a down-looking sensor is difficult.  You can get some information with vertical sounding by having many closely-spaced channels along a spectral line, but the vertical resolution is going to be very poor, *in particular* from space.  Vertical sounding is common practice for temperature and water vapour, but if you search for NO₂ vertical sounding, you will find mostly, probably exclusively, ground-based measurements.  I've tried to do CH₄ sounding and you're lucky if you can get 2 degrees of freedom of signal (DOFS), meaning a rough split in "lower half" or "upper half", but usually you get much less than that:

[image: information content]
*Source: [Holl et al., (2016)](https://www.atmos-meas-tech.net/9/1961/2016/)*

TANSO-FTS is a spectrometer carried on a satellite, PEARL-FTS is a ground-based instrument looking up.  Now this was for CH₄ (not NO₂) and for a station in the Arctic at night.  Hopefully you're not trying to do this in the Arctic and not at night, so if you try to retrieve profiles from a spectrometer (AIRS, IASI, CrIS) you can do a better job, but near-surface, probably not.  Looking up, such as PEARL-FTS does, tends to be easier than looking down because you don't have a background surface to deal with.

There are plenty of  [instruments that can retrieve NO₂ total column](https://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/gapanalyses?variable=106):

[image: total column from WMO Oscar]
*Source: [WMO Oscar](https://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/gapanalyses?variable=106)*

However, to get a good quality profile from space you need a limb sounder, [such as these](https://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/gapanalyses?mission=25):

[image: limb sounders, WMO oscar]
*Source: [WMO Oscar](https://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/gapanalyses?mission=25)*

A limb sounder gets a much better vertical resolution, but a much worse horizontal and temporal resolution (there are no geostationary limb sounders, and the concept wouldn't make much sense).  You can find [a limb viewing geometry illustration here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Limb-viewing-geometry-for-a-limb-sounder-The-instrument-measures-the-radiance-emitted-by_fig9_261013184)):

[image: limb geometry]
*Source: [Riese et al. (2014)](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Limb-viewing-geometry-for-a-limb-sounder-The-instrument-measures-the-radiance-emitted-by_fig9_261013184))*

The best signal to noise ratio are from solar occultation limb sounders such as [ACE-FTS](https://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/instruments/view/6), but those can only measure at sunrise and sunset.  And close to the surface is difficult with any limb sounder, solar occultation or not, so it is unlikely that a limb sounder would even work in your case of measurements within 50 metre from the surface.

Depending on your scientific background, I would either look for model data or use ground-based measurements.

---

- [Holl](https://www.atmos-meas-tech.net/9/1961/2016/), G., Walker, K. A., Conway, S., Saitoh, N., Boone, C. D., Strong, K., & Drummond, J. R. (2016). Methane cross-validation between three Fourier transform spectrometers: SCISAT ACE-FTS, GOSAT TANSO-FTS, and ground-based FTS measurements in the Canadian high Arctic. Atmospheric Measurement Techniques, 9(5), 1961-1980.
- Riese, M. & Oelhaf, H. & Preusse, P. & Blank, Joerg & Ern, M. & Friedl-Vallon, Felix & Fischer, H. & Guggenmoser, Tobias & Höpfner, Michael & Hoor, Peter & Kaufmann, M. & Orphal, Johannes & Ploeger, Felix & Spang, Reinhold & Suminska-Ebersoldt, O. & Ungermann, Jörn & Vogel, B. & Woiwode, W.. (2014). Gimballed Limb Observer for Radiance Imaging of the Atmosphere (GLORIA) scientific objectives. Atmospheric Measurement Techniques. 7. 1915-1928. 10.5194/amt-7-1915-2014.

Comment: I think I'll stick with the option to combine Sentinel-5P data with some model to estimate near-surface NO₂. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let us suppose, that the pollutant distributes in the lower 10 km
layer (H), and its concentrations (C) are equal on each altitude for more simple calculations. [mol/m<sup>2</sup>] must be converted to [mg/m<sup>3</sup>] for comparison with national threshold standards. Therefore, the near-ground value in [mg/m<sup>3</sup>] is:

C = (C<sub>col</sub>/H) * M * A,

where,

- C<sub>col</sub> is the pollutant column content [mol/m<sup>2</sup>],
- M is the molar mass [g/mol],
- A is a constant, equals to 1000, for conversion from [g/m<sup>3</sup>] to [mg/m<sup>3</sup>].
- H is expressed in [m].

REF:
DOI:10.28974/idojaras.2021.2.6

Comment: Although it seems so simple, it may actually work for me. Still, I need to try this method in practice. I don't mark it as the right answer for letting other people suggest alternative solutions.